# XML parsing with pass-through capability

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a requirement for low memory footprint while processing XML files upwards of 400-500MB size. This means that I can have the file loaded in-memory only once at any point in time (e.g. in a string object). The data structure is such that the elements nest in only a few levels, but are many in number (i.e. many rows of data but grouped to only a couple of levels).

During processing, I need to forward some of the data directly (i.e. exactly as read from the file, unicode character-for-character) to another stream. In other parts of the file, I need to remove/add information (usually in the form of attribute values) and possibly forward the result in a byte-consistent way to another stream (i.e. removing or adding data the same way will always produce the same result).

I've looked into XmlReader and XmlTextReader but they don't provide a way to get the exact text of the node that was Read(). Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of problem you're seeing with XmlReader? Have you checked whether XmlReaderSettings can help? (e.g. by setting IgnoreWhitespace to false.) Note that things like entity references could cause problems in terms of not being presented exactly as they are in the file, but that usually indicates that you're not really treating it as XML...

Comment: @JonSkeet Perhaps you don't understand. For instance, when the Xml(Text)Reader reads the node `<xyz a1="abc" a2="def">` (which is an element opening), I need to be able to get that exact string besides the programmatically accessible breakdown of the element. Am I making myself clearer? (no offense meant at any time)

Comment: Ah, so not just text nodes - the content of element nodes, including spaces? Ick. I wouldn't really expect and XML parser to give you that - it sounds like you're treating it as plain text rather than the XML document model.

Comment: Yes, you could say that I'm using an XML parser to help me splice and graft XML while at the same time wanting to move characters around. The final question is "_is_ there a way to do it with XmlReader?" It's starting to look impossible. I'm leaning towards a simpler approach with a text parser (the formatting as a text file is mostly straightforward and stable).

Comment: No, I don't know of any way to do this with XmlReader, as that's not what it's designed for - it's designed to treat it as XML rather than text, basically. It sounds like you want a lexer but not a parser, as it were...